# Как сохранить все рисунки с Майкрософт Ворд файла .dос?

Tags: vba, ms-word, doc

Добрый день. Как экспортировать все рисунки с .doc файла? Спасибо.

Есть .doc файл с изображениями и текстом, нужно сохранить в отдельную папку все изображения. Лучше чтобы можно было выбрать формат.

Comment: Нужно сразу все изображения сохранить. Помню был макрос какой-то.

Comment: http://pdfaid.com/extract-images-doc.aspx

Comment: Сохранить как html и рядом папке найдёте все ресурсы, в том числе картинки в двух вариантах.
А вообще, этот вопрос не по теме форума.

Comment: [http://www.programmersforum.ru/showthread.php?t=38102](http://www.programmersforum.ru/showthread.php?t=38102)